# graph_tool: re-index vertex ids to be consecutive integers

Tags: graph-tool

After applying a vertex filter on a given graph, I'd like to re-index the new filtered graph so that the vertex ids are consecutive integers.

For example:

```
from graph_tool import load_graph
g = load_graph("path-to-graph")   # assuming there are `n` nodes
vfilt = g.new_vertex_filter('bool')
# ...modify vfilt so that `k` nodes are filtered out 
g.set_vertex(filter)
new_g = reindex_vertices(g)  # is there such a function?
assert list(map(int, new_g.vertices())) == list(range(n-k))  # 1...n-k
```

is there a function similar to `reindex_vertices` in `graph_tool`?

### update

one solution is:

```
n2i = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(g.vertices())}  # mapping from old node id to new node id

# then create a new graph and also reindex the edges
new_g = Graph()
new_g.add_edge_list([(n2i[e.source()], n2i[e.target()]) for e in g.edges()])
```

Comment: Does my solution work?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
new_g = gt.Graph(new_g, prune = True)
```

Now `new_g` would have consecutive vertex indices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `vorder` parameter of `Graph()` function call.
It is of type [PropertyMap](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.PropertyMap)

```
N = int(g.num_vertices())
newindexes = graph.new_vertex_property("int")
for v in graph.vertices():
    newnames[v] = (int(v)+3)%N    #Hash function to jumble the values
new_g = Graph(g,vorder=newindexes)
```

You may change `newindexes` to [these datatypes](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.PropertyMap)

This will "re-index" your new graph. :)

Comment: Please don't add "signature" links to your answers. They will be edited out, or your answers will be deleted.